# how to enable past dates in DatePicker?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery.datePicker-2.1.2 as a date picker. The problem is I need to select past days, but the calendar doesn't allow me. Anyone knows what to change there?

I've tried to delete `disabled` functions in CSS file, but it just made the past dates available but stil I cudn't choose them.

```
(function($){

    $.fn.extend({
renderCalendar  :   function(s)
        {
            var dc = function(a)
            {
                return document.createElement(a);
            };

            s = $.extend({}, $.fn.datePicker.defaults, s);

            if (s.showHeader != $.dpConst.SHOW_HEADER_NONE) {
                var headRow = $(dc('tr'));
                for (var i=Date.firstDayOfWeek; i<Date.firstDayOfWeek+7; i++) {
                    var weekday = i%7;
                    var day = Date.dayNames[weekday];
                    headRow.append(
                        jQuery(dc('th')).attr({'scope':'col', 'abbr':day, 'title':day, 'class':(weekday == 0 || weekday == 6 ? 'weekend' : 'weekday')}).html(s.showHeader == $.dpConst.SHOW_HEADER_SHORT ? day.substr(0, 1) : day)
                    );
                }
            };

            var calendarTable = $(dc('table'))
                                    .attr(
                                        {
                                            'cellspacing':2,
                                            'className':'jCalendar'
                                        }
                                    )
                                    .append(
                                        (s.showHeader != $.dpConst.SHOW_HEADER_NONE ? 
                                            $(dc('thead'))
                                                .append(headRow)
                                            :
                                            dc('thead')
                                        )
                                    );
            var tbody = $(dc('tbody'));

            var today = (new Date()).zeroTime();

            var month = s.month == undefined ? today.getMonth() : s.month;
            var year = s.year || today.getFullYear();

            var currentDate = new Date(year, month, 1);


            var firstDayOffset = Date.firstDayOfWeek - currentDate.getDay() + 1;
            if (firstDayOffset > 1) firstDayOffset -= 7;
            var weeksToDraw = Math.ceil(( (-1*firstDayOffset+1) + currentDate.getDaysInMonth() ) /7);
            currentDate.addDays(firstDayOffset-1);

            var doHover = function()
            {
                if (s.hoverClass) {
                    $(this).addClass(s.hoverClass);
                }
            };
            var unHover = function()
            {
                if (s.hoverClass) {
                    $(this).removeClass(s.hoverClass);
                }
            };  

            var w = 0;
            while (w++<weeksToDraw) {
                var r = jQuery(dc('tr'));
                for (var i=0; i<7; i++) {
                    var thisMonth = currentDate.getMonth() == month;
                    var d = $(dc('td'))
                                .text(currentDate.getDate() + '')
                                .attr('className', (thisMonth ? 'current-month ' : 'other-month ') +
                                                    (currentDate.isWeekend() ? 'weekend ' : 'weekday ') +
                                                    (thisMonth && currentDate.getTime() == today.getTime() ? 'today ' : '')
                                )
                                .hover(doHover, unHover)
                            ;
                    if (s.renderCallback) {
                        s.renderCallback(d, currentDate, month, year);
                    }
                    r.append(d);
                    currentDate.addDays(1);
                }
                tbody.append(r);
            }
            calendarTable.append(tbody);

            return this.each(
                function()
                {
                    $(this).empty().append(calendarTable);
                }
            );
        },
datePicker : function(s)
        {           
            if (!$.event._dpCache) $.event._dpCache = [];

            // initialise the date picker controller with the relevant settings...
            s = $.extend({}, $.fn.datePicker.defaults, s);

            return this.each(
                function()
                {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var alreadyExists = true;

                    if (!this._dpId) {
                        this._dpId = $.event.guid++;
                        $.event._dpCache[this._dpId] = new DatePicker(this);
                        alreadyExists = false;
                    }

                    if (s.inline) {
                        s.createButton = false;
                        s.displayClose = false;
                        s.closeOnSelect = false;
                        $this.empty();
                    }

                    var controller = $.event._dpCache[this._dpId];

                    controller.init(s);

                    if (!alreadyExists && s.createButton) {
                        // create it!
                        controller.button = $($.dpText.TEXT_CHOOSE_DATE)
                                .bind(
                                    'click',
                                    function()
                                    {
                                        $this.dpDisplay(this);
                                        this.blur();
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                );
                        $this.after(controller.button);
                    }

                    if (!alreadyExists && $this.is(':text')) {
                        $this
                            .bind(
                                'dateSelected',
                                function(e, selectedDate, $td)
                                {
                                    this.value = selectedDate.asString();
                                }
                            ).bind(
                                'change',
                                function()
                                {
                                    if (this.value != '') {
                                        var d = Date.fromString(this.value);
                                        if (d) {
                                            controller.setSelected(d, true, true);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        if (s.clickInput) {
                            $this.bind(
                                'click',
                                function()
                                {
                                    $this.dpDisplay();
                                }
                            );
                        }
                        var d = Date.fromString(this.value);
                        if (this.value != '' && d) {
                            controller.setSelected(d, true, true);
                        }
                    }

                    $this.addClass('dp-applied');

                }
            )
        },
dpSetDisabled : function(s)
        {
            return _w.call(this, 'setDisabled', s);
        },
    dpSetStartDate : function(d)
        {
            return _w.call(this, 'setStartDate', d);
        },
dpSetEndDate : function(d)
        {
            return _w.call(this, 'setEndDate', d);
        },
dpGetSelected : function()
        {
            var c = _getController(this[0]);
            if (c) {
                return c.getSelected();
            }
            return null;
        },
dpSetSelected : function(d, v, m)
        {
            if (v == undefined) v=true;
            if (m == undefined) m=true;
            return _w.call(this, 'setSelected', Date.fromString(d), v, m, true);
        },
    dpSetDisplayedMonth : function(m, y)
        {
            return _w.call(this, 'setDisplayedMonth', Number(m), Number(y), true);
        },
dpDisplay : function(e)
        {
            return _w.call(this, 'display', e);
        },
dpSetRenderCallback : function(a)
        {
            return _w.call(this, 'setRenderCallback', a);
        },
dpSetPosition : function(v, h)
        {
            return _w.call(this, 'setPosition', v, h);
        },
dpSetOffset : function(v, h)
        {
            return _w.call(this, 'setOffset', v, h);
        },
dpClose : function()
        {
            return _w.call(this, '_closeCalendar', false, this[0]);
        },
        // private function called on unload to clean up any expandos etc and prevent memory links...
        _dpDestroy : function()
        {
            // TODO - implement this?
        }
    });
var _w = function(f, a1, a2, a3, a4)
    {
        return this.each(
            function()
            {
                var c = _getController(this);
                if (c) {
                    c[f](a1, a2, a3, a4);
                }
            }
        );
    };

    function DatePicker(ele)
    {
        this.ele = ele;

        // initial values...
        this.displayedMonth     =   null;
        this.displayedYear      =   null;
        this.startDate          =   null;
        this.endDate            =   null;
        this.showYearNavigation =   null;
        this.closeOnSelect      =   null;
        this.displayClose       =   null;
        this.selectMultiple     =   null;
        this.verticalPosition   =   null;
        this.horizontalPosition =   null;
        this.verticalOffset     =   null;
        this.horizontalOffset   =   null;
        this.button             =   null;
        this.renderCallback     =   [];
        this.selectedDates      =   {};
        this.inline             =   null;
        this.context            =   '#dp-popup';
    };
    $.extend(
        DatePicker.prototype,
        {   
            init : function(s)
            {
                this.setStartDate(s.startDate);
                this.setEndDate(s.endDate);
                this.setDisplayedMonth(Number(s.month), Number(s.year));
                this.setRenderCallback(s.renderCallback);
                this.showYearNavigation = s.showYearNavigation;
                this.closeOnSelect = s.closeOnSelect;
                this.displayClose = s.displayClose;
                this.selectMultiple = s.selectMultiple;
                this.verticalPosition = s.verticalPosition;
                this.horizontalPosition = s.horizontalPosition;
                this.hoverClass = s.hoverClass;
                this.setOffset(s.verticalOffset, s.horizontalOffset);
                this.inline = s.inline;
                if (this.inline) {
                    this.context = this.ele;
                    this.display();
                }
            },
            setStartDate : function(d)
            {
                if (d) {
                    this.startDate = Date.fromString(d);
                }
                if (!this.startDate) {
                    this.startDate = (new Date()).zeroTime();
                }
                this.setDisplayedMonth(this.displayedMonth, this.displayedYear);
            },
            setEndDate : function(d)
            {
                if (d) {
                    this.endDate = Date.fromString(d);
                }
                if (!this.endDate) {
                    this.endDate = (new Date('12/31/2999')); // using the JS Date.parse function which expects mm/dd/yyyy
                }
                if (this.endDate.getTime() < this.startDate.getTime()) {
                    this.endDate = this.startDate;
                }
                this.setDisplayedMonth(this.displayedMonth, this.displayedYear);
            },
            setPosition : function(v, h)
            {
                this.verticalPosition = v;
                this.horizontalPosition = h;
            },
            setOffset : function(v, h)
            {
                this.verticalOffset = parseInt(v) || 0;
                this.horizontalOffset = parseInt(h) || 0;
            },
            setDisabled : function(s)
            {
                $e = $(this.ele);
                $e[s ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('dp-disabled');
                if (this.button) {
                    $but = $(this.button);
                    $but[s ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('dp-disabled');
                    $but.attr('title', s ? '' : $.dpText.TEXT_CHOOSE_DATE);
                }
                if ($e.is(':text')) {
                    $e.attr('disabled', s ? 'disabled' : '');
                }
            },
            setDisplayedMonth : function(m, y, rerender)
            {
                if (this.startDate == undefined || this.endDate == undefined) {
                    return;
                }
                var s = new Date(this.startDate.getTime());
                s.setDate(1);
                var e = new Date(this.endDate.getTime());
                e.setDate(1);

                var t;
                if ((!m && !y) || (isNaN(m) && isNaN(y))) {
                    // no month or year passed - default to current month
                    t = new Date().zeroTime();
                    t.setDate(1);
                } else if (isNaN(m)) {
                    // just year passed in - presume we want the displayedMonth
                    t = new Date(y, this.displayedMonth, 1);
                } else if (isNaN(y)) {
                    // just month passed in - presume we want the displayedYear
                    t = new Date(this.displayedYear, m, 1);
                } else {
                    // year and month passed in - that's the date we want!
                    t = new Date(y, m, 1)
                }
                // check if the desired date is within the range of our defined startDate and endDate
                if (t.getTime() < s.getTime()) {
                    t = s;
                } else if (t.getTime() > e.getTime()) {
                    t = e;
                }
                var oldMonth = this.displayedMonth;
                var oldYear = this.displayedYear;
                this.displayedMonth = t.getMonth();
                this.displayedYear = t.getFullYear();

                if (rerender && (this.displayedMonth != oldMonth || this.displayedYear != oldYear))
                {
                    this._rerenderCalendar();
                    $(this.ele).trigger('dpMonthChanged', [this.displayedMonth, this.displayedYear]);
                }
            },
            setSelected : function(d, v, moveToMonth, dispatchEvents)
            {
                if (v == this.isSelected(d)) // this date is already un/selected
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (this.selectMultiple == false) {
                    this.selectedDates = {};
                    $('td.selected', this.context).removeClass('selected');
                }
                if (moveToMonth && this.displayedMonth != d.getMonth()) {
                    this.setDisplayedMonth(d.getMonth(), d.getFullYear(), true);
                }
                this.selectedDates[d.toString()] = v;

                var selectorString = 'td.';
                selectorString += d.getMonth() == this.displayedMonth ? 'current-month' : 'other-month';
                selectorString += ':contains("' + d.getDate() + '")';
                var $td;
                $(selectorString, this.ele).each(
                    function()
                    {
                        if ($(this).text() == d.getDate())
                        {
                            $td = $(this);
                            $td[v ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('selected');
                        }
                    }
                );

                if (dispatchEvents)
                {
                    var s = this.isSelected(d);
                    $e = $(this.ele);
                    $e.trigger('dateSelected', [d, $td, s]);
                    $e.trigger('change');
                }
            },
            isSelected : function(d)
            {
                return this.selectedDates[d.toString()];
            },
            getSelected : function()
            {
                var r = [];
                for(s in this.selectedDates) {
                    if (this.selectedDates[s] == true) {
                        r.push(Date.parse(s));
                    }
                }
                return r;
            },
            display : function(eleAlignTo)
            {
                if ($(this.ele).is('.dp-disabled')) return;

                eleAlignTo = eleAlignTo || this.ele;
                var c = this;
                var $ele = $(eleAlignTo);
                var eleOffset = $ele.offset();

                var $createIn;
                var attrs;
                var attrsCalendarHolder;
                var cssRules;

                if (c.inline) {
                    $createIn = $(this.ele);
                    attrs = {
                        'id'        :   'calendar-' + this.ele._dpId,
                        'className' :   'dp-popup dp-popup-inline'
                    };
                    cssRules = {
                    };
                } else {
                    $createIn = $('body');
                    attrs = {
                        'id'        :   'dp-popup',
                        'className' :   'dp-popup'
                    };
                    cssRules = {
                        'top'   :   eleOffset.top + c.verticalOffset,
                        'left'  :   eleOffset.left + c.horizontalOffset
                    };

                    var _checkMouse = function(e)
                    {
                        var el = e.target;
                        var cal = $('#dp-popup')[0];

                        while (true){
                            if (el == cal) {
                                return true;
                            } else if (el == document) {
                                c._closeCalendar();
                                return false;
                            } else {
                                el = $(el).parent()[0];
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    this._checkMouse = _checkMouse;

                    this._closeCalendar(true);
                }


                $createIn
                    .append(
                        $('<div></div>')
                            .attr(attrs)
                            .css(cssRules)
                            .append(
                                $('<h2></h2>'),
                                $('<div class="dp-nav-prev"></div>')
                                    .append(
                                        $('<a class="dp-nav-prev-year" href="#" title="' + $.dpText.TEXT_PREV_YEAR + '">&lt;&lt;</a>')
                                            .bind(
                                                'click',
                                                function()
                                                {
                                                    return c._displayNewMonth.call(c, this, 0, -1);
                                                }
                                            ),
                                        $('<a class="dp-nav-prev-month" href="#" title="' + $.dpText.TEXT_PREV_MONTH + '">&lt;</a>')
                                            .bind(
                                                'click',
                                                function()
                                                {
                                                    return c._displayNewMonth.call(c, this, -1, 0);
                                                }
                                            )
                                    ),
                                $('<div class="dp-nav-next"></div>')
                                    .append(
                                        $('<a class="dp-nav-next-year" href="#" title="' + $.dpText.TEXT_NEXT_YEAR + '">&gt;&gt;</a>')
                                            .bind(
                                                'click',
                                                function()
                                                {
                                                    return c._displayNewMonth.call(c, this, 0, 1);
                                                }
                                            ),
                                        $('<a class="dp-nav-next-month" href="#" title="' + $.dpText.TEXT_NEXT_MONTH + '">&gt;</a>')
                                            .bind(
                                                'click',
                                                function()
                                                {
                                                    return c._displayNewMonth.call(c, this, 1, 0);
                                                }
                                            )
                                    ),
                                $('<div></div>')
                                    .attr('className', 'dp-calendar')
                            )
                            .bgIframe()
                        );

                var $pop = this.inline ? $('.dp-popup', this.context) : $('#dp-popup');

                if (this.showYearNavigation == false) {
                    $('.dp-nav-prev-year, .dp-nav-next-year', c.context).css('display', 'none');
                }
                if (this.displayClose) {
                    $pop.append(
                        $('<a href="#" id="dp-close">' + $.dpText.TEXT_CLOSE + '</a>')
                            .bind(
                                'click',
                                function()
                                {
                                    c._closeCalendar();
                                    return false;
                                }
                            )
                    );
                }
                c._renderCalendar();

                $(this.ele).trigger('dpDisplayed', $pop);

                if (!c.inline) {
                    if (this.verticalPosition == $.dpConst.POS_BOTTOM) {
                        $pop.css('top', eleOffset.top + $ele.height() - $pop.height() + c.verticalOffset);
                    }
                    if (this.horizontalPosition == $.dpConst.POS_RIGHT) {
                        $pop.css('left', eleOffset.left + $ele.width() - $pop.width() + c.horizontalOffset);
                    }
                    $(document).bind('mousedown', this._checkMouse);
                }
            },
            setRenderCallback : function(a)
            {
                if (a == null) return;
                if (a && typeof(a) == 'function') {
                    a = [a];
                }
                this.renderCallback = this.renderCallback.concat(a);
            },
            cellRender : function ($td, thisDate, month, year) {
                var c = this.dpController;
                var d = new Date(thisDate.getTime());

                // add our click handlers to deal with it when the days are clicked...

                $td.bind(
                    'click',
                    function()
                    {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        if (!$this.is('.disabled')) {
                            c.setSelected(d, !$this.is('.selected') || !c.selectMultiple, false, true);
                            if (c.closeOnSelect) {
                                c._closeCalendar();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );

                if (c.isSelected(d)) {
                    $td.addClass('selected');
                }

                // call any extra renderCallbacks that were passed in
                for (var i=0; i<c.renderCallback.length; i++) {
                    c.renderCallback[i].apply(this, arguments);
                }


            },
            // ele is the clicked button - only proceed if it doesn't have the class disabled...
            // m and y are -1, 0 or 1 depending which direction we want to go in...
            _displayNewMonth : function(ele, m, y) 
            {
                if (!$(ele).is('.disabled')) {
                    this.setDisplayedMonth(this.displayedMonth + m, this.displayedYear + y, true);
                }
                ele.blur();
                return false;
            },
            _rerenderCalendar : function()
            {
                this._clearCalendar();
                this._renderCalendar();
            },
            _renderCalendar : function()
            {
                // set the title...
                $('h2', this.context).html(Date.monthNames[this.displayedMonth] + ' ' + this.displayedYear);

                // render the calendar...
                $('.dp-calendar', this.context).renderCalendar(
                    {
                        month           : this.displayedMonth,
                        year            : this.displayedYear,
                        renderCallback  : this.cellRender,
                        dpController    : this,
                        hoverClass      : this.hoverClass
                    }
                );

                // update the status of the control buttons and disable dates before startDate or after endDate...
                // TODO: When should the year buttons be disabled? When you can't go forward a whole year from where you are or is that annoying?
                if (this.displayedYear == this.startDate.getFullYear() && this.displayedMonth == this.startDate.getMonth()) {
                    $('.dp-nav-prev-year', this.context).addClass('disabled');
                    $('.dp-nav-prev-month', this.context).addClass('disabled');
                    $('.dp-calendar td.other-month', this.context).each(
                        function()
                        {
                            var $this = $(this);
                            if (Number($this.text()) > 20) {
                                $this.addClass('disabled');
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    var d = this.startDate.getDate();
                    $('.dp-calendar td.current-month', this.context).each(
                        function()
                        {
                            var $this = $(this);
                            if (Number($this.text()) < d) {
                                $this.addClass('disabled');
                            }
                        }
                    );
                } else {
                    $('.dp-nav-prev-year', this.context).removeClass('disabled');
                    $('.dp-nav-prev-month', this.context).removeClass('disabled');
                    var d = this.startDate.getDate();
                    if (d > 20) {
                        // check if the startDate is last month as we might need to add some disabled classes...
                        var sd = new Date(this.startDate.getTime());
                        sd.addMonths(1);
                        if (this.displayedYear == sd.getFullYear() && this.displayedMonth == sd.getMonth()) {
                            $('dp-calendar td.other-month', this.context).each(
                                function()
                                {
                                    var $this = $(this);
                                    if (Number($this.text()) < d) {
                                        $this.addClass('disabled');
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (this.displayedYear == this.endDate.getFullYear() && this.displayedMonth == this.endDate.getMonth()) {
                    $('.dp-nav-next-year', this.context).addClass('disabled');
                    $('.dp-nav-next-month', this.context).addClass('disabled');
                    $('.dp-calendar td.other-month', this.context).each(
                        function()
                        {
                            var $this = $(this);
                            if (Number($this.text()) < 14) {
                                $this.addClass('disabled');
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    var d = this.endDate.getDate();
                    $('.dp-calendar td.current-month', this.context).each(
                        function()
                        {
                            var $this = $(this);
                            if (Number($this.text()) > d) {
                                $this.addClass('disabled');
                            }
                        }
                    );
                } else {
                    $('.dp-nav-next-year', this.context).removeClass('disabled');
                    $('.dp-nav-next-month', this.context).removeClass('disabled');
                    var d = this.endDate.getDate();
                    if (d < 13) {
                        // check if the endDate is next month as we might need to add some disabled classes...
                        var ed = new Date(this.endDate.getTime());
                        ed.addMonths(-1);
                        if (this.displayedYear == ed.getFullYear() && this.displayedMonth == ed.getMonth()) {
                            $('.dp-calendar td.other-month', this.context).each(
                                function()
                                {
                                    var $this = $(this);
                                    if (Number($this.text()) > d) {
                                        $this.addClass('disabled');
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            _closeCalendar : function(programatic, ele)
            {
                if (!ele || ele == this.ele)
                {
                    $(document).unbind('mousedown', this._checkMouse);
                    this._clearCalendar();
                    $('#dp-popup a').unbind();
                    $('#dp-popup').empty().remove();
                    if (!programatic) {
                        $(this.ele).trigger('dpClosed', [this.getSelected()]);
                    }
                }
            },
            // empties the current dp-calendar div and makes sure that all events are unbound
            // and expandos removed to avoid memory leaks...
            _clearCalendar : function()
            {
                // TODO.
                $('.dp-calendar td', this.context).unbind();
                $('.dp-calendar', this.context).empty();
            }
        }
    );

    // static constants
    $.dpConst = {
        SHOW_HEADER_NONE    :   0,
        SHOW_HEADER_SHORT   :   1,
        SHOW_HEADER_LONG    :   2,
        POS_TOP             :   0,
        POS_BOTTOM          :   1,
        POS_LEFT            :   0,
        POS_RIGHT           :   1
    };
    // localisable text
    $.dpText = {
        TEXT_PREV_YEAR      :   'Предыдущий год',
        TEXT_PREV_MONTH     :   'Предыдущий месяц',
        TEXT_NEXT_YEAR      :   'Следующий год',
        TEXT_NEXT_MONTH     :   'Следующий месяц',
        TEXT_CLOSE          :   'Закрыть',
        TEXT_CHOOSE_DATE    :   '<p><u>выбрать дату</u></p>'
    };
    // version
    $.dpVersion = '$Id: jquery.datePicker.js 15 2008-12-17 04:40:18Z kelvin.luck $';

    $.fn.datePicker.defaults = {
        month               : undefined,
        year                : undefined,
        showHeader          : $.dpConst.SHOW_HEADER_SHORT,
        startDate           : undefined,
        endDate             : undefined,
        inline              : false,
        renderCallback      : null,
        createButton        : true,
        showYearNavigation  : true,
        closeOnSelect       : true,
        displayClose        : false,
        selectMultiple      : false,
        clickInput          : false,
        verticalPosition    : $.dpConst.POS_TOP,
        horizontalPosition  : $.dpConst.POS_LEFT,
        verticalOffset      : 0,
        horizontalOffset    : 0,
        hoverClass          : 'dp-hover'
    };

    function _getController(ele)
    {
        if (ele._dpId) return $.event._dpCache[ele._dpId];
        return false;
    };

    // make it so that no error is thrown if bgIframe plugin isn't included (allows you to use conditional
    // comments to only include bgIframe where it is needed in IE without breaking this plugin).
    if ($.fn.bgIframe == undefined) {
        $.fn.bgIframe = function() {return this; };
    };


    // clean-up
    $(window)
        .bind('unload', function() {
            var els = $.event._dpCache || [];
            for (var i in els) {
                $(els[i].ele)._dpDestroy();
            }
        });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: post the code on how u initialize datepicker

Comment: Try this [link](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerPastDate.html)

Comment: this is the code from datepicker that I have, and I have no idea where  and what to change inside? [http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/scripts/jquery.datePicker.js]

Comment: @Patrick Have you look at my link ?? [http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerPastDate.html](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerPastDate.html)

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm adding that function, and it is still not working. Maybe I'm adding in the wrong place?

Comment: @Patrick Can you post your code or can make jsfiddle for the same?

Comment: @jaychapani see above, i've added the code into the question.

Comment: @Patrick I guess you have posted date picker code!!! Try this [fiddle==http://jsfiddle.net/V4JTq/](http://jsfiddle.net/V4JTq/) it is working fine here

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16523/discussion-between-jaychapani-and-patrick)

Comment: @jaychapani's above link is working!!! problem solved!

Comment: @Patrick should I post this as an answer??

Comment: @jaychapani yes I guess it will be right.

Comment: @Patrick I have added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add following js and css files:

### JS

- http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/scripts/jquery.datePicker.js
- http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/scripts/date.js

### CSS

- http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/styles/datePicker.css

Then you can call date picker function like

```
$(function() {
    $('your selector').datePicker({
        startDate: '01/01/1996'
    });
});​
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/V4JTq/)

Answer (score 1):

simple datePicker with dates in the past selectable

```
$(function()
{
    $('.datepick').datePicker({startDate:'01/01/1997'});
});
```

simple datePicker with only dates in the past selectable

```
$(function()
{
    $('.datepick').datePicker(
        {
            startDate: '01/01/1970',
            endDate: (new Date()).asString()
        }
    );
});
```

for more information check [this link](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/) its great

Answer (score 0):

Hey search for defaultDate option to set and place the below link where you are calling datePicker plugin.

```
defaultDate: '-2m',
```

This option is to set the date of 2 month back

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no defaultDate :(

Comment: ok you posted code after my comment...
check this [link](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerStartEnd.html)